# Prevent two div become one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div tag. In the `style.css` file, I set attribute for button and button span. The result I want is that, when I create 2 buttons in 2 div tag, it makes 2 rows. But when I make 2 buttons in each div, it always becomes one line. I also set `display: block` for both buttons and button span, but still not get correct result.

```css
    .button {
      display: block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 200px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .button span:after {
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
      white-space: pre;
    }
    
    .button:hover span {
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
    
    .button:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
    }
    button:focus {
      outline:0;
    }
    
    div {
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style=''>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">   
    </head>
    <body style="width:550px;">
    <div id='message' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="hdqual"><button class='button'><span>Button 1</span></button></div>
    <div id="sdqual"><button class='button'><span>Button 2</span></button></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are floating div's to the right and they don't take up 100% of the width... and you shouldn't do that anyway

Comment: Did you try setting `width: 100%;` beside `display: block` and `clear: both`?

Comment: not sure what you are doing with all this float etc. CSS look pretty much complicated for simple buttons in rows...

Comment: Oh thanks so much. After adding clear: both; and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: pre;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
button:focus {
  outline:0;
}

.outer {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html style=''>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">     
</head>
<body style="width:550px;">
<div id='message' style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="outer">
<div id="hdqual"><button><span>Button 1</span></button></div>
<div id="sdqual"><button><span>Button 2</span></button></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you put an outer div around 2 buttons and float that to the right it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **"div {  float: right; }"** and the divs will be in different lines, since youre defining the style to all divs, they'll always will be in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing you add width:100%; and display:block;

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: pre;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

div {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body style="width:550px;">
    <div id='message' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="hdqual">
      <button class='button'><span>Button 1</span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="sdqual">
      <button class='button'><span>Button 2</span></button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not the correct awnser, the div selector probably shouldn't be floated in the first place.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Thanks. I have updated it. but if you would like to set button on left side then he will have to use float:left so technically I am not wrong. Probably it's your view.